# Writing my own linux shell I/O redirect '>' function

Tags: c, linux, shell, io-redirection

I am writing the redirect function that writes the output of a command to a given filename.

For example:

`echo Hello World > hello.txt` would write 'Hello World' into hello.txt.

`ls -al > file_list.txt` would write the list of all file/directory names in the current directory into file_list.txt.

My function so far is defined as:

```
int my_redirect(char **args, int count) {
    if (count == 0 || args[count + 1] == NULL) {
        printf("The redirect function must follow a command and be followed by a target filename.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *filename = args[count + 1];

    //Concatenates each argument into a string separated by spaces to form the command
    char *command = (char *) malloc(256);
    for (int i = 0; i < (count); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            strcpy(command, args[i]);
            strcat(command, " ");
        }
        else if (i == count - 1) {
            strcat(command, args[i]);
        }
        else {
            strcat(command, args[i]);
            strcat(command, " ");
        }
    }

    //command execution to file goes here

    free(command);
    return 1;
}
```

where `args[count]` is `">"`.

How can I execute the command given by the string from `args[0]` to `args[count - 1]` into the file given at `args[count + 1]`?

**EDIT**

These are the instructions we have been given:

"Improve your shell by adding a redirect for stdout to a file. Only attempt after completing Feature 1. Parse the line for >, take everything before as command, and the first word after as the filename (ignore <, >>, | etc).

Standard out is written out to file descriptor 1 (stdin is 0, stderr is 2). So this task can be achieved by opening the file, and copying it’s file descriptor over to 1 with dup2 system call.

```
int f = open( filename , O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) ;
dup2( f , 1 ) ;
```

Note: Using system call open not library wrapper fopen here."

Comment: It seems to me you're asking for the entirety of the assignment here. You should try to come up with something on your own, and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: As a starting point, a real shell would call `fork()` to create a child process. Inside the child, it would use something like your `dup2()` sample to open the output file and assign it to stdout. Then it'd call `execve()` or [one of the other exec functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) to actually execute the command (take a look at execvp in particular). The exec functions take the command in the form of a list of arguments, so it shouldn't be necessary to concatenate them into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to solve this problem in a special way, so it works only for a narrow range of problems, like capturing stdout of a command into a file, you can avoid reinventing the wheel using the `popen()` function from `<stdio.h>`.

Sketch of the program:

1. Determine output file name
2. Open output file for writing
3. Determine command and arguments
4. Construct the command string from the args up to the `>`.
5. Call `FILE *cmd = popen(command, "r");`
6. Read line from `cmd` stream, write to output file
7. Goto 6 while not EOF on the `cmd` stream.
8. `pclose(cmd)`, `fclose` output stream

Do this only if your instructor does not expect you to use fork, dup, and friends.